# ListView only showing 6 items

Tags: android, listview, layout, render

hello foreign friends!

I'm trying to list the return of a JSON call, however, when viewing the items in a Android ListView, only 6 items are displayed (the last one, cut in half).

- I checked the API call and there are about 20 items returned;
- Verified the retrofit object and it contains an array with 20 objects;

In my pov, the problem is in the Layout that for some reason is not rendering all the objects.

Below is the xml:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#050505">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayoutView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapseToolBarLayoutView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="15dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/singlePostPathView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/background_transp" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/singleTitleView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:text="Top 10 Morgan Freeman Movies"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="38dp"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/likeButtonVIew"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/userLikesIconView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_like"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/singleTitleView" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/likeButtonVIew"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_like_btn"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/userRateView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="719 Curtidas"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userLikesIconView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/userLikesIconView"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/userLikesIconView"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/watchesIconVIew"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_rd"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/userLikesIconView"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/userLikesIconView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userRateView"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/watchesVIew"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/singleTitleView"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:text="0 de 10 Assistidos"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/watchesIconVIew"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/userLikesIconView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/userLikesIconView"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayoutView"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/similar_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/items_similar" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is there any property I need to set in order to achieve the goal?

Comment: This is not a full valid layout.. Looks like it should be wrapped in a `ConstraintLayout` that is dismissed from your shared layout, can you share the entire layout and also a pic of what you expect to see

Comment: Could you provide your MainActivity, the List Item and the full Layout as @Zain wrote. Then we are able to investigate further. Cheers!

Comment: I'm terribly sorry! I didn't notice that the Editor took off the top showing the Layout root. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all no blame but your `layout` should definitely set up in a more advanced way. There could be more done for performance and logic.
Check that your `rootView` is a `CoordinatorLayout` combined with a `NestedScrollView` to scroll inside the whole screen.

Be aware, **NEVER** use a `ScrollView` with `ListView` or `RecyclerView` - again - **NEVER**!

My reference: [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView)

To see anything I needed to add a `CoordinatorLayout`. I hope your rootView isn't the `AppBarLayout`.

Another point, make your `ListView` scrollable. If it isn't that explain, why the `ListItems` are cutted away after 6 items. That is caused by the `Layout` too, the `ListView` has no chance to scroll, yet. It should be scrollable by default, btw.

And last but not least, check if your List is limited or looks like this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
return yourArrayList.length;
}
```

Comment: My code was completely weird. I've updated it now as it really should be (the root layout was missing, I'm sorry)

Comment: As I said :) The rootView wasn't there. I had to add it by myself. Feel free to tick this as the correct answer. Glad it works :) Cheers!